# SSRS 2008 with VS 2012 Error ORA-12638

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, bids

I have the system below:

- Windows 7 64Bits
- Visual Studio 2012 with Business Intelligence Template
- Oracle XE 11g Win 32bit
- Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20
- ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit for .Net

I tried to access Oracle localhost DataBase from SQL Developer and everything is allright.

But, when I try to access the same localhost database from inside Visual Studio 2012 on a Report Server Project, I get the error `ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed.`

I have already reinstalled the ODT but without any change.

I have already changed the line below in `sqlnet.ora`:

From:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

To:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE,NTS) OR
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

I have already restarted Oracle service without any change.

What can I do ?

This error had happened from one day to another. One day before, it was working, and suddenly it stopped to work.

I do not want to reinstall Oracle, because I can access it from SQL Developer. So, I think it is a VS 2012 problem.

Comment: I am confused as SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2012 is an add on to Visual Studio 2010.  Are you talking about designing HOSTED reports(RDL files) that you publish to an SSRS Server or local reports (RDLC files) that go along with your client?  Are you using the Datasource directly for Oracle and storing the credentials if you are using RDL?  If you are making a local report you need to authenticate differently.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 with Business Intelligence Template is an add on to the VS 2012 to permit create reports inside VS. You can create a solution where you define your reports, connections etc. My reports are rdls whish I save locally and after that I send them to a report server (I am not publishing them form VS). The datasource is pointing to an Oracle DB, using the correct credentials. I can use a local Oracle Db or point to a remote one. Each one has its own credentials to connect.

Comment: I have already identified that the problem was my ODT driver, which is used to connect VS to Oracle. I dont know why, but it corrupts and stops working. I´ve installed again and everything starts working.

Comment: Well that is great then.  I know that drivers of cross types are a pain to troubleshoot.  Glad you got it working.  I usually go more generic with the connection string and use a factory when it does not work easily.